# InvalidoperationException on DESERIALIZE

Tags: c#, serialization

I want to deserialize a XML into an object but continuously getting following exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).     ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
at   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderBAObjectSchema.Read18_BAObjectSchema()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   at Siemens.BASys.BAObjectCreator.SchemaHandler.Deserialize[T](String path, Boolean throwException) in ....\SchemaHandler.cs:line 34
```

Code I am using

```
` public static T Deserialize<T>(string path, bool throwException)
    {

        T root = default(T);
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    root = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        return root;
    }`
```

XML I am using looks correct but not sure why error is coming

Following is the sample part of XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ObjectSchema>
  <Controllers>



  </Controllers>
</ObjectSchema>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Any helpful information on the context of this exception would be appreciated

Comment: The exception says that the `root element is missing`... That your Xml is invalid. How are you serializing your object to Xml? Do you have a sample of the xml that is failing?

Comment: Added XML in Question

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code and XML. This happens because of the `StreamReader`. Streams are forward mode only reader once it reaches EOF the XMLSerializer throws error when trying to read from the same Stream with state EOF *i.e.* the cursor was found at End of file and there's no root tag.

Instead of using TextReader user XMLTextReader which allows multiple readings.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
 {
    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs))
      {
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
         root = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
      }

 }
```